# Search Engine Optomisation

Tags: seo, search-engine

My neighbour popped over last night to ask me for help with regards to his company's website. He said that it used to be ranked pretty high on Google but has since fallen off completely.

Now, I'm a Windows App programmer hence my request for help. I took a look and there the meta tags seem ok. I recommended that he add a <h1>heading</h1> to the pages with a page title to help reinforce the content.

I also suggested that finding related websites and getting them to link to his site was good for search ranking.

Are there any other general strategies / tools that could help?

He site is: http://www.colofinder.co.uk/

ps. BTW: this isn't just an attempt to have StackOverflow link to my neighbour's site - I'm aware that links from SO don't add to its ranking.

Comment: In fairness Mike, I'm from England where we spell it "Optimisation" - so I was only slightly wrong :-)

Comment: @Mike Two: I don't think "correcting" s to z was needed or useful.

Comment: @Alex - you are correct. I was overzealous. I rolled it back. I was not thinking clearly at the time

Comment: @LeeOades I'm sorry. I do know that. I lived there myself for 18 months. I just wasn't thinking. I sort of jumps out me that way and I corrected without thinking. I have rolled it back.

Comment: @MikeTwo: maybe I shouldn't have mentioned it. :) OTOH, optOmisation isn't all that unreasonable in the context of seeing or not seeing something. :)

Comment: @Alex - that's hilarious. I rolled it back and never noticed the real typo. The rollback just reverts to the original text. I didn't re-type it. At this point I'm going to leave it as is. I would probably find a new spelling.

Answer (score 1):

Go to http://ooyes.net/blog/a-step-by-step-15-minute-seo-audit-%28a-sample-from-seo-secrets%29 and read it. Then go to http://www.searchenginejournal.com/55-quick-seo-tips-even-your-mother-would-love/6760/ and read it. Then go to your friends site and look at it with that information in mind. Off the top of my head, I would add flip the company name and page title in the "title" tags. Look at the google analytics account and see how people are coming to the site. That will give you an idea of where you should start your efforts to build a workable base.

Answer (score 0):

First of all he needs to be make sure that his website contents are well managed and to the point. Then Page title has to be pin point, meta tags are obsolete so try meta description. Then Main Heading should be under h1 tag, sub heading under h2 and further sub heading h3. Try to update your website one in a month.

Use community websites like Facebook, Twitter and linkidin and other related forums for posting updates about completed projects and must give inbound links. You can use your company name as an inlink to your primary website and project name as an inlink of subpage of your company website.

Keep on posting at least once in a week. Post website URL to online directories will be a great help. Do not use Blackhat SEO techniques like cloaking. Do not use any invisible text/div in your website. Make sure that whenever you give your website link any where, give the most to the point and appropriate link.

Your link should have to have that stuff against you are posting your link/sublink. Make a section on your website for tag clouds/google tags, this will be a great attraction for search engines and they will link your website to other popular websites.

Make sure these tags should be directed to top ranking website which should have relevant material. I hope this will help. Feel free if you have trouble to understand anything i have mentioned above. Best of Luck

Comment: Just a friendly pointer, when your answer contains this about of text, I'd advice using paragraphs and perhaps even subtitles to make it more readable.

Comment: Thanks for your friendly pointer. I will keep it in mind. Look i have changed it already. Thanks again LOL :)